# remove/fill gaps inside polygon qgis

Tags: qgis, shapefile, grass-gis, grass-7.0

I have created a polygon from grass gis and found small triangle like structure inside the polygon (sometimes at the edge to outside), that I want to remove/fill. I tried with geometry check to fix but not succeed. Is there any efficient way to fix that.
[image]

Comment: Efficient, as in automatically?

Comment: Yes..like we can fix by manual editing that i don't want as you said automatically :)  or using some algorithm

Comment: @bikuser - Have you tried the **Fill holes** tool from the _Processing Toolbox_?

Comment: @Joseph, Yes I tried, but it does not help...but simplify polygon from plugin able to fill but it changed my shapefile

Comment: How about generating a new convex hull vector map and patch than into the existing map?